# passing a smalldate time variable in sql?

Tags: sql-server-2008, variables, date

There is an sp,

```
EXEC Dbo.CREATE_A_PEACEFULL_WORL 'A',2,??
```

?? presents a smalldatetime variable, 
the date is must be like; 24.02.2010 00:00:00

how can i pass it?

Comment: Can you clarify your question please. I'm not sure if you're trying to convert a date in the format dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss to a smalldatetime or if you're just trying to work out how to pass a date into an SP

Comment: is this for SQL Server 2008?  the only hints are: `EXEC`, `dbo.` and `smalldatetime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
EXEC Dbo.CREATE_A_PEACEFULL_WORL 'A',2
    ,SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),@yourSmallDate,104)
    +' '+CONVERT(varchar(8),@yourSmallDate,108)
```